# Wix templates not showing up in project list

Tags: visual-studio, wix, votive

I downloaded and installed WiX 3.5 and, from what I understood, the templates for WiX projects should be installed and available when I try to make a new project.

Did I miss a step somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the New Project Dialog, there should be an entry in installed templates call Windows Installer XML.The types of project are listed under there. I did nothing special, just run the installer, if they are not there try a repair. Wix 3.6 is out now if you can move to that.

Update: Based on your last comment I did some more digging, it would appear that you are right, Visual Studio Express does not support Votive, which is the Wix Addin.

See http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html

It says the following:

> Votive will not work on the Express SKUs of Visual Studio

I guess the alternative would be do use the command line tools, which would probably take much longer.

Comment: Tried repairing and had no luck. Does VS Express not support WiX? I know it doesn't support alot of pluggins and I'm not sure if this one qualifies

Answer (score -2):

Wix 3.5 & Wix 3.7 do not install any templates in Visual Studio 2010 proffesional.
One possible solution is this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3448085-d6f0-4569-a670-0a18c825169b